# UWP wait for Textbox.Textchanged event to fire

Tags: c#, uwp, textbox, textchanged

How to change the text in a UWP Textbox and wait for it's TextChanged to complete before moving on, or not fire the TextChanged event at all.

**The scenario.** 
Main UI shows a red flag if the TextBox text changes - however, I need to reset it occasionally (TextBox.Text = "", or some other text), when that happens, I want my red flag to go green.

**Expected process flow**

```
TextBox.Text = ""
TextBox.Changed event fires - causing my flag to go red
Reset flag to green
```

**Actual process flow**

```
TextBox.Text = ""
Reset flag to green
TextBox.Changed event fires - causing my flag to go red
```

**What I think is happening**
Setting the TextBox.Text causes an event to be added to dispatch queue, which doesn't fire until the UI thread is idle, this means the next command (Reset flag to green) happens before the TextChanged event is consumed. It's also possible that the event is waiting for the TextBox to finish rendering before firing the event, but I can't be certain.

**Solution?** 
Any help appreciated.

Comment: Your reasoning in _What I think is happening_ is right. You could wait to reset the flag on the next update. However that would result in a red flag showing up for a split second. Is there a particular reason the flag cannot simply be green any time `TextBox.Text` is `""`?

Comment: This is how I'm proceeding; a 100 ms delay to allow the events to fire (await on UI thread) then reset the flag; the flash of red is not an issue - thanks - i'll let you know how it goes

Comment: I did not quite understand what you want to do. Please describe your requirements in detail.

Comment: Without going into full detail, I have a UI indicator that shows red if the text in a TextBox is dirty, e.g. the text has changed and the changes have not been 'saved', or green if the text is saved. That part is simple; monitor the TextChanged event and if fired, the text was changed, therefore the indicator is red. When I save the text, change the indicator back to green. However, if I load new text from the 'saved' location, and set the text, I need the indicator to be green; unfortunately, the text changed event fires causing it to go red. the event fires at some point, not immediately.

Comment: What is firing what?  There is no code in this question?  My expectation is I win the lottery, actual result, I haven't.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is so simple: use a Boolean flag to distinguish when to fire “red flag” and when the green one.

Comment: A boolean flag doesn't work because the TextChanged event happens after I set everything; I'd have to set a delay, but how long?

Answer (score 0):

In "real life", I would be creating a custom control based on a textbox and defining all of the states in Blend and probably add a dirty state or something and drive it all via a boolean property.
However, here some proof of concept code that seems to do what I gather you need.  I think the only real difference to what you have been trying is that I am tracking the "old value" and comparing it when the text changes to determine its cleanliness.  The magic reset also controls that old value.

control code:

```
namespace DirtyTextBox
{
    public class DirtyNotifyingTextBox : TextBox
    {
        public DirtyNotifyingTextBox()
        {
            this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof(TextBox);
            DataContextChanged += DirtyNotifyingTextBox_DataContextChanged;
        }

        private void DirtyNotifyingTextBox_DataContextChanged(Windows.UI.Xaml.FrameworkElement sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.DataContextChangedEventArgs args)
        {
            _originalValue = this.Text;
            TextChanged += DirtyNotifyingTextBox_TextChanged;
            SetToGreen();
        }

        private string _originalValue { get; set; }

        private void DirtyNotifyingTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.Text != _originalValue)
            {
                SetToRed();
            }
            else
            {
                SetToGreen();
            }
        }

        private void SetToGreen()
        {
            this.BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Color.FromArgb(255, 50, 205, 0));
        }

        private void SetToRed()
        {
            this.BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 0, 0));
        }

        public void Reset()
        {
            Reset(string.Empty);
        }

        public void Reset(string resetValue)
        {
            _originalValue = resetValue;
            this.Text = resetValue;
        }

        protected override void OnApplyTemplate()
        {
            base.OnApplyTemplate();
        }
    }
}
```

sample usage:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <local:DirtyNotifyingTextBox x:Name="dtextbox" Width="250" Height="50" />
    <Button Content="reset" Click="Reset" Margin="10 0" />
    <Button Content="reset with value" Click="ResetWithValue" Margin="10 0" />
    <Button Content="change text with code" Click="UpdateText" Margin="10 0" />
</StackPanel>
```

code behind:

```
private void Reset(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    dtextbox.Reset();
}

private void ResetWithValue(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    dtextbox.Reset("Magic Reset");
}

private void UpdateText(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    dtextbox.Text = "updated text";
}
```

Comment: I like this approach however my concern would be with large amount of text - lets say the textbox is holding a log file, this could be hundreds of thousands of lines, I unsure what the practical limit is as the TextBox in UWP is broken over a certain size of text. Large text would mean two copies in memory and the comparison could be costly - I'll have to check on resource cost, if the user edits text, then every keystroke has to take a copy and perform a compare. Inefficient, but might do the job.